# Trying to display JSON data from API as an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, discord.js

So I've been trying to make a Discord Bot in Node.js, Im fetching data from an external api and using the BOT to display the data, problem is that when I call the function, its showing one by one instead of everything in one message.
I want to display everything in one message.

```
const token = 'my discord token is here';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!inventario') {
      let getInv =  async () => {
          let response = await axios.get('my api link where im getting the info is here')
          let inventario = response.data
          return inventario
      }
      let inventarioValue = await getInv ()
      var inv = inventarioValue.total_inventory_count
      msg.channel.send(`Total de Itens no inventário: ${inventarioValue.total_inventory_count} \nSkins:\n`);
       for (var i=0;i<inv;i++)
{

    var itens = inventarioValue.descriptions[i].market_name
    msg.channel.send(itens);
}
    }
  });
client.login(token);
```

I want to execute this inventarioValue.descriptions[i].market_name, then after executing showing the full result instead of showing one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map object array element and add to message. For a better visual reflection, you can add them to embed.

```js
const token = 'my discord token is here';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!inventario') {
        let getInv = async () => {
            let response = await axios.get('my api link where im getting the info is here')
            let inventario = response.data
            return inventario
        }
        let inventarioValue = await getInv()
        var inv = inventarioValue.total_inventory_count
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        embed.setDescription(`${inventarioValue.descriptions.map(val => val.market_name).join('\n')}`)
        msg.channel.send(`Total de Itens no inventário: ${inventarioValue.total_inventory_count} \nSkins:\n`, embed);
    }
});
client.login(token);
```